# Как запустить daemon process в Java?

Tags: java, daemon

У меня есть сервер, который должен быть запущен как `daemon`. Как лучше это сделать?

Comment: без бубна не обойтись, а как бы ты это делал?

Comment: ОС какая ? Или сервер это тоже java ?

Comment: 4 win: есть какая-то бесплатная тулза которая позволяет создать сервис для веб сервера (помню наверняка для tomcat, jboss, для других хз)

Comment: Вот здесь - [Немного черной магии в UNIX](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/demons.php) живенько написано.

Comment: Если Вам дали исчерпывающий ответ, то закройте вопрос, нажав на зеленую галочку рядом с правильным ответом

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от операционной системы и приложения.

Если приложение само не поддерживает запуск как демон (с перенаправлением IO и игнорированием сигналов), в линуксах запустить приложение как демона можно при помощи команды

`nohup java -jar myServer.jar &`

Это перенаправит вывод сервера в файл nohup.out и остоединит его от терминала.

Если сервер распространенный, то у него будет командный файл для запуска сервера как демон. Стоит почитать документацию по установке такого сервера в систему.

Comment: @Mr_Mig, боюсь разочаровать Вас, но nohup демона не делает. Остается управляющий терминал, сессия, PID родителя. Да и дескрипторы 1 и 2 перенаправляются в nohup.out, а не в /dev/null (как у большинства демонов) (хотя, демон понятие условное).

Я обычно делал лишний fork() (вместо родителя получаем 1 (init)), потом setsid() (это обязательно), ну и игры с дескрипторами (0 обычно из /dev/null), маской сигналов (зависит от задачи). 

Очевидно, все это применимо для \*nix. Как делают в винде, не знаю.

Просто ТС не уточнил ОС, поэтому ничего раньше писать не стал.

Answer (score 0):

а [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) Вам  не подходит?

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о Java-приложении, то наиболее быстрые и удобные варианты это [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) или [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/) - суть обоих состоит в том что тебе нужно описать минимальую конфигурацию и реализовать свою логику, а фреймворк предоставляет все остальное, в том числе и для [старта демона](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-service).
И там и там есть куча примеров, которые достаточо скопипастить, и получаешь готовую болванку приложения, в которую перекидываешь свою логику

Если уж совсем лень, то могут помочь врапперы, такие как [Apache Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/) и [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html)